# проблема с self.image = pygame.draw.circle

Tags: python, pygame

```
# Игра Shmup - 1 часть
# Cпрайт игрока и управление
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

# Задаем цвета
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

# Создаем игру и окно
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Shmup!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, (200, 100), 50, 10)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
        self.speedx = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 8
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

# Цикл игры
running = True
while running:
    # Держим цикл на правильной скорости
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Ввод процесса (события)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # проверка для закрытия окна
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Обновление
    all_sprites.update()

    # Рендеринг
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    # После отрисовки всего, переворачиваем экран
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

выдает следующие :
File "C:\Users\Апостол Моисей\Desktop\programing\py\boss.py", line 29, in **init**
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'get_rect'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pygame.draw.circle` возвращает объект типа `Rect`, у которого нет метода `get_rect()`.

Вот переработанный код, надеюсь поможет:

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

# Задаем цвета
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

# Создаем игру и окно
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Shmup!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.cicrle_radius = 50
        self.circle_center = [WIDTH//2, HEIGHT-10-self.cicrle_radius]
        self.speedx = 8

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, self.circle_center, self.cicrle_radius, 10)

    def update(self, left, right):
        if left:
            self.vel = -self.speedx
        if right:
            self.vel = self.speedx

        if not(left or right):
            self.vel = 0

        self.circle_center[0] += self.vel
        if self.circle_center[0] < 0:
            self.circle_center[0] = 0
        if self.circle_center[0] > WIDTH:
            self.circle_center[0] = WIDTH

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()

# Цикл игры
running = True
left = right = False
while running:
    # Держим цикл на правильной скорости
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Ввод процесса (события)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # проверка для закрытия окна
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: # Клавиша ВПРАВО
                right = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:  # Клавиша ВЛЕВО
                left = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: # Клавиша ВПРАВО
                right = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:  # Клавиша ВЛЕВО
                left = False


    # Обновление
    all_sprites.update()

    # Рендеринг
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    player.update(left, right)
    player.draw(screen)
    #all_sprites.draw(screen)
    # После отрисовки всего, переворачиваем экран
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: как я тогда могу создать фигуру круг таким же образом ?

Comment: @дэнчик дополнил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
# Игра Shmup - 1 часть
# Cпрайт игрока и управление
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

# Задаем цвета
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

# Создаем игру и окно
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

pygame.display.set_caption("Shmup!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

#        self.image = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, (200, 100), 50, 10)
        ball = pygame.image.load("ball.png")                                # +++
        self.image = ball.convert()                                         # +++

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()                                  

        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
        self.speedx = 0


    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 8
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()                          
all_sprites.add(player)

# Цикл игры
running = True
while running:
    # Держим цикл на правильной скорости
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Ввод процесса (события)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # проверка для закрытия окна
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Обновление
    all_sprites.update()

    # Рендеринг
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # аргумент 1 должен быть pygame.Surface, а не pygame.Rect
    all_sprites.draw(screen)                                          

    # После отрисовки всего, переворачиваем экран
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

---

**ball.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
class HIT(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 38))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.radius = 20
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius, 5)
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
```

ребят увидев ваш ответ и пытаясь преобразовать к своей игре всё время были ошибки, постородав 2 часа я выяснил проблему и получился вот такой код проще